# spring mvc login form validation

Tags: spring, forms, validation, spring-mvc, authentication

I have a simple spring mvc login application SpringHibernateLogin with form validation.The validation is working fine which mns when there is a case of missing username/password or even for invalid credentials it returns me to the same login page with corresponding error message,but the url being dispalyed is incorrect.For all cases the url get appended with welcome page(like http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateLogin/login1/hello1.jsp),here in my case the welcome page being hello1.jsp.Ideally it should return  http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateLogin/login1 only.

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center" style="color:Tomato">Spring Hibernate Demo</h2>
<a href="login1">Existing user</a>
<br><br>

</body>
</html>

login1.jsp



<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form name="frm" method="post" action="hello1" modelAttribute="log1">

    <form:label path="username">USERNAME</form:label>
    <form:input path="username"/>
    <form:errors path="username" cssClass="error c"></form:errors>
    <br><br>

    <form:label path="password">PASSWORD</form:label>
    <form:input path="password" type="password"/>
    <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
    <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>


</form:form>

</body>
</html
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>SpringHibernateLogin</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login1.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-

mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring1-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.jt.*" />


   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/classes/messages"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.jt.shlogin;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.jt.model.login1model;
import com.jt.validator.LoginClientSideValidation;


@Controller
public class HelloController{

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String homepage(Model model)
    {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login1")
    public String firstPage(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("log1",new login1model());
        return "login1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello1")
    public ModelAndView printHello(@ModelAttribute("log1")login1model log1,ModelMap model,BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest req) {


        ModelAndView model1=null;
        LoginClientSideValidation v=new LoginClientSideValidation();
        v.validate(log1,result);
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {

            model1= new ModelAndView("login1");

        }
        else
        {

            String name = req.getParameter("username");
            model.addAttribute("message1", "Hi "+name+" welcome for Spring MVC Training");
            model1=new ModelAndView("hello1");

        }
        return model1;
   }

}
```

LoginClientSideValidation.java

```
package com.jt.validator;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.jt.model.login1model;

@Component
public class LoginClientSideValidation implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {

        return login1model.class.isAssignableFrom(arg0);
    }


    public void validate(Object arg0, Errors arg1) {
        login1model log1=(login1model)arg0;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "username", "log1.username.empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "password", "log1.password.empty");

    }

}
```

messages.properties

```
log1.username.empty="Username cannot be empty";
log1.password.empty="Password cannot be empty";
```

Folder Structure

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr71u.jpg)

Comment: This happened to me as well one billion time, and I always forget how I did solve it, have you tried to use action="/hello1" instead of "hello1" ?

Comment: @OEH Thanks for the reply...however i tried as u mentioned but doesn't work.